# Extract associated value from enum regardless of the case in Swift

Tags: swift, enums

I want to get the associated value of swift enum object, is there a way to do it shorter/better than in switch statement below?

```
enum Test {
    case a(Int), b(Int), c(Int)
}

func printValue(_ t: Test) {
    switch t {
        case .a(let v), .b(let v), .c(let v): print("value \(v)")
    }
}
```

Comment: No, there isn't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code for extracting the associated value from multiple enums is the most economical and easy-to-read, there's no need to improve it.

However, the fact that you are looking to extract an associated value regardless of `enum`'s case suggests that you are not using associated values correctly: rather than associating a value with each individual case, you should create a composite type that holds the `Int` and an `enum` without an associated value, i.e.

```
enum Test {
    case a, b, c
}
class MyClass {
    var num : Int
    var tst : Test
}
```

Now that the associated value is "outside" each `enum` element, it can be accessed independently of the case, and you can also give it a meaningful name, which adds to readability of your program.

Comment: I agree. Unfortunately, the enum comes from a third party lib, so I don't have control over it.

Comment: @frangulyan `enum` being external to your code is perhaps the only valid reason to use this code in the first place.

Comment: Just a reference, if you can think of a reason behind their decision - https://github.com/parse-community/ParseLiveQuery-iOS-OSX/blob/master/Sources/ParseLiveQuery/Subscription.swift#L71 I guess Facebook's Parse team was behind the codes initially before it went open-source.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't rely on every case having an associated value or having an associated value of the same type. While that may be the case now, especially if you're interacting with an external library, it may change in the future. The whole point of associated values is to allow different types with different cases. If the party who controls the enum decides to add a case, the compiler will warn you that you don't have a case for that type.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use mirror type - it's not the better way, but it can be helpful in some cases:

```
enum Test {
    case a(Int), b(Int), c(Int)
}

func printValue(_ t: Test) {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: t)
    print(mirror.children.first?.value ?? "")
}

printValue(.a(15))
```

Also using if/case like this, it's a shorter way if you need to extract value only from one case, sometimes it's helpful:

```
if case .a(let val) = t {
    print("value \(val)")
}
```

Or may be raw value will fit better for your case:

```
enum Test: Int {
    case a = 1
    case b = 2
    case c = 5
}

func printValue(_ t: Test) {
    print("value \(t.rawValue)")
}

printValue(.a)
```

Comment: The second example isn't an associated value

Comment: @paper1111, yes it's not, I'm just suggesting another approach.